# Why does this SQL query take 8 hours to finish?

Tags: sql

There is a simple SQL `JOIN` statement below:

```
SELECT     
    REC.[BarCode]
   ,REC.[PASSEDPROCESS]
   ,REC.[PASSEDNODE]
   ,REC.[ENABLE]
   ,REC.[ScanTime]
   ,REC.[ID]
   ,REC.[Se_Scanner]
   ,REC.[UserCode]
   ,REC.[aufnr]
   ,REC.[dispatcher]
   ,REC.[matnr]
   ,REC.[unitcount]
   ,REC.[maktx]
   ,REC.[color]
   ,REC.[machinecode]
   ,P.PR_NAME
   ,N.NO_NAME
   ,I.[inventoryID]
   ,I.[status]
   FROM  tbBCScanRec as REC  
       left join TB_R_INVENTORY_BARCODE as R 
         ON    REC.[BarCode] = R.[barcode] 
           AND REC.[PASSEDPROCESS] = R.[process]
           AND REC.[PASSEDNODE] = R.[node]
       left join TB_INVENTORY  as I 
         ON R.[inventid] = I.[id]
       INNER JOIN  TB_NODE as N 
         ON N.NO_ID  =  REC.PASSEDNODE
       INNER JOIN  TB_PROCESS  as P 
         ON P.PR_CODE    = REC.PASSEDPROCESS
```

The table `tbBCScanRec` has 556553 records while the table `TB_R_INVENTORY_BARCODE` has 260513 reccords and the table `TB_INVENTORY` has 7688. However, the last two tables (`TB_NODE` and `TB_PROCESS`) both have fewer than 30 records.

Incredibly, when it runs in SQL Server 2005, it takes 8 hours to return the result set.

Why does it take so much time to execute?

If the two `inner join`s are removed, it takes just ten seconds to finish running.

What is the matter?

There are at least two `UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX`es.

One is `IX_INVENTORY_BARCODE_PROCESS_NODE` on the table `TB_R_INVENTORY_BARCODE`, which covers four columns (`inventid`, `barcode`, `process`, and `node`).

The other is `IX_BARCODE_PROCESS_NODE` on the table `tbBCScanRec`, which covers three columns (`BarCode`, `PASSEDPROCESS`, and `PASSEDNODE`).

Comment: I can't recommend any specific tutorial, but you need to learn to understand execution plans. There are options in SSMS to turn on the execution plan - if you could add that, we may be able to give you some pointers (better to post an XML query plan that an image, though). Also, it's generally better to work with the Actual rather than the Estimated plan, but the Estimated plan may be enough if it's going to take another 8 hours to get the Actual.

Answer (score 2):

Well, standard answer to questions like this:

1. Make sure you have all the necessary indexes in place, i.e. indexes on `N.NO_ID`, `REC.PASSEDNODE`, `P.PR_CODE`, `REC.PASSEDPROCESS`
2. Make sure that the types of the columns you join on are the same, so that no implicit conversion is necessary.

Comment: There are AT least TOW UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEXES

Answer (score 1):

You are working with around (556553 *30 *30) 500 millions of rows.
You probably have to add [indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx) on your tables.

If you are using SQL server, you can watch the plan query to see where you are losing time.
See the documentation here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190623(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190623%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

The query plan will help you to create indexes.

Comment: I don't follow your estimation of 500 million rows. Can you explain?

Comment: The estimated maximum number of lines **handled during processing** is the Cartesian product. This is multiplication of the number of lines of each table: the "worst" scenario...

Comment: Ok, so weren't talking about the size of the result set? Then you missed two tables in your calculation, didn't you? `TB_R_INVENTORY_BARCODE` with 260513 rows and `TB_INVENTORY` with 7688 rows

Comment: the result set has the same number of records as table tbBCScanRec

Comment: @WangHu: Yes the result has maximum the same number of records as table tbBCScanRec, but during the processing, the number of rows increasing (to complete the join). The number of rows isn't the problem here. First, you have to see your **execution plan** and adjust indexes.

Comment: I just add an index on TB_R_INVENTORY_BARCODE which only covers the three colums(barcode,process,node)  involved in left join ; the performace improves hugely. I thought that the index IX_INVENTORY_BARCODE_PROCESS_NODE could make sense befor but it did not....

Comment: @WangHu: Nice. Does 'hugely' means the problem is solve ? how many time do you have now ? have you add Index on N.NO_ID and P.PR_CODE ?

Comment: nearly 18 secs , Oh the indexes on NO_ID AND PR_CODE already exist

Comment: Awesome! on tables like yours (with a large number of rows) performance indexes are truly amazing. Glad if I helped you...

Answer (score 0):

When you check the indexing, there should be clustered indexes as well - the nonclustered indexes use the clustered index, so not having one would render the nonclustered useless. Out-dated statistics could also be a problem.

However, why do you need to fetch ALL of the data? What is the purpose of that? You should have WHERE clauses restricting the result set to only what you need.